# Can not find "Start Action" in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net

I am a freshman at VS.

When I try to write a class library and find the debug configurations to change the "Start Action" but I can not find it.

So, somebody can teach me how can I do to make it visible.

[image]

Thank you all so much

Comment: Generally a class library wouldn't have a "start action" because you can't start a class library.  Did you mean to create a console application instead?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Here's a link to [official documentation/sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio) on what a `Class Library` is (vs a `Console` application, which is something that (may) _use_ a `class library`)

Comment: A class library can't start, you load it from a console or GUI project that call methods defined in it. You can't run a DLL, you run an EXE that use DLLs.

Comment: Do you want to set an executable for debugging that uses your dll? Then change **Project** in the line **Launch** accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start a class library because it is just a collection of functions. There is no starting point for the compiler to find.

Typically, to test a class library you would build a simple console application or even WinForms UI. These projects have a main method that can actually be run, and they can call methods in your library.

Just don't forget to add your library as a project reference. (Add -> Project Reference -> Library -> Ok)